# Remove entire column of table dynamic and n number of columns jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table

```
if (target >= 4) {
        $('.floor').slice(target).parent().parent().remove();
        //since I select the .floor input box, I have to use the parent() function two times, to move the selector up to the <tr> element
    } else {
        $('.floor').slice(4).parent().parent().remove();
        //since I select the .floor input box, I have to use the parent() function two times, to move the selector up to the <tr> element
    }
```

This is how I delete n number of row depending on a number in a text field which will then be the value of target.
How can I make the same concept except that I need to delete entire column?

`Update`

```
<table id="flooring">
    <tr>
        <td><strong><p>Flooring</p></strong>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <hr/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>1st Floor</span>

        </td>
        <td>
            <span>2nd Floor</span>

        </td>
        <td>
            <span>3rd Floor</span>

        </td>
        <td>
            <span>4th Floor</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span>Reinforced Concrete</span>
        </td>
        <td>

            <input type="checkbox" class="floor1st checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />

        </td>
        <td>

            <input type="checkbox" class="floor2nd checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />

        </td>
        <td>

            <input type="checkbox" class="loor3rd checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />

        </td>
        <td>

            <input type="checkbox" class="floor4th checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />

        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><span>Plain Cement</span>
        </td>
        <td>

            <input type="checkbox" class="floor1st checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />

        </td>
        <td>

            <input type="checkbox" class="floor2nd checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />

        </td>
        <td>

            <input type="checkbox" class="floor3rd checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />

        </td>
        <td>

            <input type="checkbox" class="floor4th checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span>Marble</span>
        </td>
        <td>

            <input type="checkbox" class="floor1st checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />

        </td>
        <td>

            <input type="checkbox" class="floor2nd checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />

        </td>
        <td>

            <input type="checkbox" class="floor3rd checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />

        </td>
        <td>

            <input type="checkbox" class="floor4th checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span>Wood</span>
        </td>
        <td>

            <input type="checkbox" class="floor1st checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />

        </td>
        <td>

            <input type="checkbox" class="floor2nd checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />

        </td>
        <td>

            <input type="checkbox" class="floor3rd checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />

        </td>
        <td>

            <input type="checkbox" class="floor4th checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span>Tiles</span>
        </td>
        <td>

            <input type="checkbox" class="floor1st checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />

        </td>
        <td>

            <input type="checkbox" class="floor2nd checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />

        </td>
        <td>

            <input type="checkbox" class="floor3rd checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />

        </td>
        <td>

            <input type="checkbox" class="floor4th checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />

        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

This is the default html and I also add column here depending on input text. When the previous input is bigger than the current that is the time I want to delete entire column that is what this is for.

Comment: Can we have the `HTML`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (target >= 4) {
        $("table#.floor tr").find('td:eq('+target+')').nextAll().remove();
    } else {
        $("table#.floor tr").find('td:nth-child(5)').nextAll().remove();
    }
```

I ended up using this code. Hopefully someone will be helped by this small code. The code above will choose all `td` with the `index` of target and all td next to it

Answer (score 1):

Use an `:nth-child` selector:

```
$("#tableid").find("tr :nth-child("+target+")").remove();
```

To remove all columns starting from `target`:

```
var col;
while ((col = $("#tableid").find("tr :nth-child("+target+")")).length) {
    col.remove();
}
```

Comment: that will only remove one column right how about there if i want to delete more..the idea is from target down up should be removed

Comment: I can't think of an easy way to do that other than a loop. There are `:gt` and `:lt` selectors, but no `:child-gt` or `:child-lt` selectors.

Comment: i tried doing loop but if it is you how would you do it with loop?

Comment: It starts with 0. Do you really need me to explain things that can easily be read in the documentation?

Comment: sorry my bad the first td has label so i must not be include how to exlcude first td? i did it this way and the remove did not fire`.find('tr td:not(:nth-child(1)):nth-child('+target+')').remove();`

Comment: I don't understand the problem. It won't remove the first `td` unless `target` is `1`.

Comment: Oops, I was wrong above, it starts with 1, because that's how CSS works.